# How to return efficiently a big array of values in json and asynchronously in an ASP.NET Core action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, async-await

I am looking for the best way to return a big collection of data (without pagination) in json with an ASP.NET Core action?

I defined the best way as:

- Non-blocking: the return is asynchronous (await / async) including the JSON formatting / serialization
- Avoid the temporary allocation of the whole collection in the method body

I thought about the solution below: let's say we create our own custom json serializer which performs (via `JsonWriter`: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter.htm) the serialization asynchronously of a given the `IEnumerable<int>` and write it directly to the response body stream:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<int>> GetAsync()
{
     using(var jsonStream = _myService.GetJsonStreamAsync())
     {
         await jsonStream.CopyToAsync(HttpContext.Response.Body);
     }
}
```

Comment: "noticed some increase in memory when I fetch the process"... What does this mean? How are you measuring memory usage/allocations? If not with a dedicated memory-profiler, then this should be your first stop.

Comment: @spender:  Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64; not the best way to measure but it keeps being increased on each request (can't see the GC tick since I am using Rider but does not seem that memory is cleaned up).

Comment: The problem here is that GC doesn't necessarily return memory to the OS (and consequently remove it from the working set). Only a memory profiler can give you a true understanding of what's actually happening here.

Comment: @spender ok I double checked it works fine :x sorry for noise